# Handling Registration on Progressive Web App

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm converting part of my Python Flask application to be used as a kiosk via a progressive web app (simplest way I've been able to find to deploy it as an "app" to my managed tablets). What I'm struggling to wrap my head around is how to handle registration/assigning a device to a group so that when the app is downloaded, it caches the correct group information. Currently, my web app expects group info to be passed as a request parameter and then renders the correct information. Normally I can give that link to a client and they're good to go.

Here's expected setup process:

1. New tablet is provisioned, put into group and group policy loads Example PWA onto desktop.
2. Client receives new tablet, loads Example PWA
3. Example PWA looks for a registered device ID (UUID) and can't find it so redirects user to registration endpoint.
4. Client logs in with credentials, configures settings.
5. UUID is generated on the device (or server), saved on server side and saved in localStorage client side.
6. Client logs out
7. PWA now sees it's registered, requests resource from server (start_url) and renders correct landing page for the client based on device UUID.
8. End users can now use the kiosk

Is there a way to do step 7 without rewriting vast swaths of code to be driven by JS. What's the easiest way to get a uuid to the server so the right content is loaded? Ideally, I'd like to pass the device ID in the header but I think that means I have to intercept every request to inject that but I can't find a good tutorial on doing so. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pointing the start_url to a dedicated landing page and storing a uuid for each new device in IndexedDB while modifying the Fetch event listener to add that uuid (device_id) to the headers. New devices won't have a device ID, so server side for the landing page sees an empty device ID and redirects to a registration page. If device ID exists, it looks that value up in the database and redirects to the real start page for that client.